# Can a website detect if any chrome extension is reading the DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I want to know from within javascript in a webpage if any chrome extension installed in Chrome is reading the DOM. I want to be able to do this even if the extension does not insert any HTML or script into the DOM. Is there some way I can do this? Basically I want to prevent scraping of the website content.

I see this option

http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html

but this requires that I know the ids of the extension. I want to be able to do this more natively across all extensions that are installed.

Is there some event I can get based on when a DOM element is ready or some DOM function is called?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That is a very old post you linked to, and I don't think it's relevant anymore.

Comment: There's no way because content scripts of extensions run in [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world).

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of methods for reading the DOM, so catching everything would be difficult. However, one approach you can do is wrap individual DOM querying methods. For example:

```
const origFn = HTMLDocument.prototype.querySelector;
HTMLDocument.prototype.querySelector = function(...args) {
  const error = new Error();
  console.log(`querySelector was called. Args:`, args, ', Stack trace', error.stack);
  return orig.apply(this, args); 
}
```

This will do a `console.log` whenever `document.querySelector` is called. I'm not 100% sure if the stack trace will reference Chrome extension JavaScript, but it's worth a shot. Also, it's not guaranteed that all prototypes will be overwriteable like this.

Comment: This won't work because content scripts of extensions run in [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world).